# how to make a checkbox and check the state of it(if its correct or no)

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

hello i want to make 3 checkboxes one saying cpu, one saying gpu and one saying cll
and i want to check if the answer is correct so can u show me  how to do that

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

import pygame

window = tk.Tk()
pygame.mixer.init()
img = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\laithmaree\\PycharmProjects\\create_apps_with_python\\brainicon.ico.png')
window.title("Quiz Game")
# pygame.mixer.music.load('ForestWalk-320bit.wav')
# pygame.mixer.music.play()
# i created an icon
# i made a title


window.geometry("800x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.iconphoto(False, img)


label1 = tk.Label(window, text='Quiz App', font=("Arial Bold", 25))
label1.pack()

txtbox = tk.Entry(window, width=50)


def playbuttonclicked():
    label1.destroy()
    playbtn.destroy()
    quitbtn.destroy()
    label2 = tk.Label(window, text='What is the short form of computer science',font=("Arial Bold", 25))
    label2.pack()
    txtbox.place(x=250, y=200, height=40)

    def chkanswer():
        useranswer = txtbox.get()  # Get contents from Entry
        if useranswer == 'cs':
            lblcorrect = tk.Label(window, text='correct', )
            lblcorrect.pack()
            def delete():
                lblcorrect.destroy()
                label2.destroy()
                txtbox.destroy()
                submitbtn.destroy()
                label3 = tk.Label(window, text='whats is the short form of central proccessing unit', font=('Arial Bold', 25))
                label3.pack()
            lblcorrect.after(1001, delete)

        else:
            lblwrong = tk.Label(window, text='Try Again')
            lblwrong.pack()

            def deletefunction():
                lblwrong.destroy()

            lblwrong.after(1000, deletefunction)









    submitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Submit', font=('Arial Bold', 30), command=chkanswer, bg='red')
    submitbtn.place(x=305, y=400)
    submitbtn.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='grey'))
    submitbtn.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='red'))


playbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Play', font=("Arial Bold", 90), bg='red', command=playbuttonclicked)
playbtn.place(x=10, y=200)
playbtn.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='grey'))
playbtn.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='red'))


def quitbuttonclicked():
    window.destroy()


quitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Quit', font=("Arial Bold", 90), bg='red', command=quitbuttonclicked)
quitbtn.place(x=400, y=200)
quitbtn.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='grey'))
quitbtn.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='red'))
window.mainloop()
```

the question is label 3 (whats is the short form of central proccessing unit) and i want to make sure the answer is correct because i am creating a quiz app thx

Comment: I'd suggest removing the pygame tag as all the question is not related to it.

Comment: You mean how to add the Checkbox widget to your code and attach an event to it? Where do you want the buttons, in your home screen below 'Quiz App', or during the questions? When i run your code, i can enter the first question successfully but the second question is bugged out already (no entry). Please clarify what you want or provide more code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Checkbutton and event callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163658/tkinter-checkbutton-and-event-callback-function)

Comment: I think what you want are radiobuttons instead of checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example of how to create a Checkbutton and to attach a boolean variable and event to it:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

# callback for checkbutton
def checkbox_callback():
    is_checked = checkbox_var.get()
    print(f"The checkbox is selected: " + str(is_checked))
    
# variable to store the current value of the checkbutton
checkbox_var = tk.BooleanVar()

# checkbutton with text, variable and callback
checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(window, text="Click me", variable=checkbox_var, command=checkbox_callback)
checkbox.pack()

window.mainloop()
```